# Remove ununderstandable spaces inside my html bootstrap webpage

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following CSS and HTML code using Twitter Bootsrap 3:

```css
.container {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0; /*set left/right padding according to needs*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/**/

.container-fluid{
    height:100%;
}

html,body,.container {
    height:100%;
}


body>.container-fluid,
.container {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0; /*set left/right padding according to needs*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.row {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;

}

.row .no-float {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<body > 
<div class="container-fluid" style=" ">
    <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7 no-float" style="padding: 0 !important;border: solid blue ">


            <iframe src="http://exame.abril.com.br/tecnologia/facebook/noticias/facebook-nao-tem-planos-de-voltar-a-china-diz-executivo"  style="border: none;"></iframe>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5  no-float" style=" padding:0; border: solid red">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 100%!important; width: 100%!important;  ">
                <div class="panel-heading">QUESTIONS</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    HI


                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

When I run it, I get something a bit like this and got some extra spaces at the top and at the bottom of column grids:

[image]

And while I'm thinking that my CSS code is correct, I've tried hardly to remove those extra unknown spaces for my container-fluid to be 100% full height while keeping of course the same structure, but can't.

What's wrong ? Please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the `margin: -50px; padding: 50px 0 0 0` as it is the `margin: -50px` that cause the bottom gap, and I deleted the stray character you had just after the `<body>` tag, which caused the top gap.

In addition I cleaned up the CSS some and added a `margin: 0` to the `html, body` rule

```css
html,
body,
.container-fluid {
  margin 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body > .container-fluid {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}
.row .no-float {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7 no-float" style="padding: 0 !important;border: solid blue ">

      <iframe src="http://exame.abril.com.br/tecnologia/facebook/noticias/facebook-nao-tem-planos-de-voltar-a-china-diz-executivo" style="border: none;"></iframe>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5  no-float" style=" padding:0; border: solid red">
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 100%!important; width: 100%!important;  ">
        <div class="panel-heading">QUESTIONS</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          HI
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following at the bottom / end of your CSS

```
html, body { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hmf15baq/)

Comment: I setup this fiddle example and initially it had space like your depiction, but after added my css it corrected it.

Comment: Pretty weird ! I copied and pasted your code in my Intellij IDEA IDE. And run it with my chrome browser, and nothing changed at all :(